# Index nested field in elasticsearch from spark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

Say I have a table like this:

```
field1 field2 field3 id
a0     a030   a040   0  
a0     a031   a041   0
a0     a032   a042   0
a1     a130   a040   1
```

It's stored in parquet format. I need to read the table in in spark, do a groupBy on 'field1', and then I need to store a nested field (say, called "agg_fields") in ES that contains a list of dictionaries with values for field2 and field3, so that the documents will look like:

```
{
  "_id": "0"
  "field1" : "a0",
  "agg_fields" : [
    {
      "field2" : "a030",
      "field3" :  "a040"
    },
    {
      "field2" : "a031",
      "field3" :  "a041"
    },
    {
      "field2" : "a032",
      "field3" :  "a042"
    },
  ]
}
...
```

I can read in the table and do a groupBy:

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('some-table').groupBy('field1')
```

I can do some aggregation and send the result to es:

```
df.withColumn(
    'aggregated', concat('field2', lit('|'), 'field3')
).agg(
    collect_set(aggregated)
).withColumnRenamed(
    'collect_set(aggregated)', 'agg_fields'
).write.format(
    'org.elasticsearch.spark.sql'
).mode(
    'append'
 ).option(
    'es.mapping.id', 'id'
).options(
    **es_config
).option(
    'es.resource', my_resource
).save()
```

But I'm not sure how to change that aggregation to a nested "agg_fields" column which would be interpreted as a nested field by elasticsearch. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = spark.read.load('file:///path/to/your/example.json', format='json')
df = df.withColumn('agg_fields', f.explode(df['agg_fields']))
df = df.groupBy(df['field1']).agg(f.collect_set(f.concat_ws('|', df['agg_fields']['field2'], df['agg_fields']['field3'])).alias('agg_fields'))
```

Output:

```
+------+---------------------------------+                                      
|field1|agg_fields                       |
+------+---------------------------------+
|a0    |[a030|a040, a032|a042, a031|a041]|
+------+---------------------------------+
```

Do you mean this?